# Plot results of Grouper (2 groups and time series) pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, pandas-groupby

I would like to discover how to plot a dataset that looks like:
[image]

I have obtained it with the code:

```
df.groupby(['Feature','Type', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='d')])['value'].sum().reset_index(name = 'value')
```

Comment: Need the title to be more precise. Corrected the markup

Comment: What kind of plot you want? Scatter, bar plot, pie chart? Be more specific.

Comment: Would be great if you were more specific. I recommend reading this -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples